# Ck editors to A4 size pdf using Java itext

Tags: java, pdf, ckeditor, itext

Building a Web App which store the data in database.
Data will enter by client through Ck editor.
On save the data(html data) is getting saved in database.
Later on user can generate pdf from the data stored in database.
I am using itext api for generating pdf.

```
String data=""; //data will in html
//format since it is getting stored dd
//through Ck editor  
//some code to retrieve data from DB
//THEN pdf code.
XmlWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXhtml(pdfwriter,document,new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
```

Above code generates pdf.

But if user copy table from msword and put into Ck editor, data is getting saved in db but at the time pdf generation the table is not getting displayed properly in the pdf.
Some of the columns are not getting  printed because of size.
so how to convert that table to fit into A4 size page.

Comment: Show us the HTML the way it is stored in the database. Then we can take a look. Without that HTML, it is hard to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Create any table which contain some data

Comment: But how to make that table to be adjusted in to A4 size pdf

Comment: There are 7 `ParseHtmlTable` examples here: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker and if you try the examples, you'll notice that I have created many tables with data. So... what is your question? Do you want to fit the table on an A4 page? What about setting the width percentage to 100%. You have to be more clear if you want a good answer. Right now, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: What sort of conversion are you looking for? The question here seems to be `how to convert that table to fit...` - what table? Convert how? What are your requirements? Does "converting" mean for example this: `<table style="width: 10000px">` to `<table style="width:100%;">`? Or what do you mean? What did you try? Also, do you have a known PPI set? Do you have margins? Are the tables nested? This is too vague.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble actually the end user will copy some information from word document and past it in Ck editor.this information can contain image , tables or paragraph.we all know when we paste the word file data into Ck editor. Ck editor convert them into html tags.when user clicks on save button this html data will get saved into db and I m converting this info to pdf using above code.the  generated pdf contain all data which were their in the pdf but table which  were pasted from word to Ck editor is not getting populated properly  in the pdf. I am not setting any ppi value .